# exclude a line from wrap

Tags: wrapping

I often use the sequence `gqap` to hard wrap the current paragraph.
However I'd like some line to be excluded from the process.

Example

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
**<<--no wrap here-->>**
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

after `gqap` it becomes:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Is this possible?

Comment: Which pattern you are going to use for such exceptional lines?

Comment: I have no real preference. I'm writing a document in latex which use `%` as comment.

So far I've used to insert a single line with a single comment in the middle, which actually works fine. However, this uses a new line which I'd rather avoid.

Comment: Then, how to identify which part should be not wrapped as mentioned here?

Comment: I could use two spaces at the end of a line to instruct vim I want this line to be split exactly there. But I don't really have a preference, that is, I could also use a comment `%` at the end of a line where I want a break.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are wanting to *not* wrap if the line is below `textwidth` **and** ends with `consequat.`

```
function! ConsequatWrap() abort
  if v:char != '' || mode() == 'i'
    return 1
  endif

  let start_line = v:lnum
  let end_line = v:lnum + v:count - 1

  while start_line <= end_line
    call cursor(start_line, &l:textwidth)

    if col('.') < &l:textwidth && getline('.') !~? 'consequat\.$'
      normal! J
      let end_line -= 1
      continue
    endif

    if col('$') >= &l:textwidth
          \ && (search('consequat\.\%(\_$\)\@!', 'cbeW') == start_line
          \     || search('\s', 'cbeW') == start_line)
      execute "normal! a\<cr>"
      let end_line += 1
    endif
    let start_line += 1
  endwhile
endfunction

set formatexpr=ConsequatWrap()
```

What's happening above is that lines shorter than `textwidth` are joined to the current line, unless the line ends with `consequat.`.  Once the line is long enough to break, search backwards from `textwidth` for a space or an occurrence of `consequat.`, then insert `<cr>` right after it.

Using `formatexpr` will allow you to format using any direction or text object.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for, I'm going to try it right away.